# Parameterise doubly stochastic matrices

Tags: matrices, parametrization, gradient-descent, stochastic-matrices

Given the set of doubly stochastic matrices of dimension $n$, $D$, is it possible to find a continuous bijective mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^i \to D$ for $i \leq n^2$.

The motivation is to be able to perform gradient descent on the manifold of doubly stochastic matrices.

Comment: Are you acquainted with the [Birkhoff polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope)?

Answer (score 0):

$D$ is a compact convex set in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$, and thus a manifold with boundary.  Let's say its dimension is $d$.
Suppose $f$ existed.  The restriction of $f$ to any closed ball is a homeomorphism onto its image.  Now using the Baire category theorem, this image must have nonempty interior for some ball, and therefore we must have $i = d$. Now use [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).